# Python Geopandas throwing "Shell is not a Linear Ring" Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, geopandas

I am new to python and I am trying to open a shape file but when I open the file I am getting a message that says "Shell is not a Linear Ring" Message when I try and open it via command line. My code is two lines long so I am not really sure whats going on here...

Code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdp.read_file("tl_2016_17_tract.shp")
```

Error:

"Shell is not a LinearRing"

I've also tried opening the shape file with R and QGIS and both worked fine. I think it might have something to do with my installation of python because I was having some issues with that earlier. I can't find a good explanation of the error "Shell is not a LinearRing" anywhere!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, i was able to download and successfully open this file https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2016-state-illinois-current-census-tract-state-based which i believe is the same as yours.  I'm using geopandas 0.3.0 and fiona 1.7.8 (fiona handles the reads for geopandas) .   Regarding your error, I'm not sure what to make of it.  Maybe a corrupt file?

Answer (score 0):

A user with the exact same problem said:

> I resolved this issue - I believe it had to do with geopandas and how it was installed. I resolved it by using:
>
> conda remove geopandas
>
> I originally installed via conda-forge channel
>
> and then installing via pip:
>
> pip install geopandas
>
> I also went through and installed some packaged via homebrew, but I am not sure if that made a difference.

[Source](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/556)